# How to make single selection work in a nested RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

For our application I had to implement a nested RecyclerView. I'm getting a list of Tables from JSON and every Table has another list with groups from each table. I can get everything on the screen as requested, the problem is the selection.

I have 2 different RecyclerViews on the screen and I can not seem to get a single selection working in this environment, especially after scrolling. Every group and every table has a Toggle Button, and only one can be active at a time.

[This is how the main screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtZF9.png)

So far I've tried putting a boolean isSelected on the Model but that didn't work out at all. The closest solution I came up with was a helper class that searches every CompoundButton on-screen and deselects them all when one is selected. The problem is this helper class cant get the Buttons which are off-screen.

How I populate ParentAdapter (in MainActivity):

```java
public void setAdapter(List<Table> tableList)
    {
        RecyclerView recycler_view_parent = findViewById(R.id.recyclerparent);
        LinearLayoutManager manager=new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recycler_view_parent.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recycler_view_parent.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycler_view_parent.setItemViewCacheSize(tableList.size());
        ParentAdapter parentAdapter=new ParentAdapter(tableList,MainActivity.this);
        recycler_view_parent.setAdapter(parentAdapter);
    }
```

How i populate ChildAdapter (in onBindViewHolder of ParentAdapter):

```java
FlexboxLayoutManager manager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
            manager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
            manager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
            manager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
            manager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.BASELINE);
            holder.recycler_view_child.setLayoutManager(manager);
            holder.recycler_view_child.setHasFixedSize(true);
            adapter = new ChildAdapter(tableList, tableList.get(position).getGroups(), context);
            holder.recycler_view_child.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The desired output should be only 1 Table OR Group at a time can be toggled (in total, not one from every RecyclerView) and the state should be the same after scrolling/device rotation).

I did a lot of research over the last days on this subject and I can not seem to find a working example of nested RecyclerView with single selection over both RVs.

So does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? I think the biggest issue is telling the Parent that a Button in Child was toggled and vice-versa.

I think for the ParentAdapter it should look something like this:

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Table table = tablelist.get(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;

    if (table.isTableSelected()) {
        viewHolder.toggletable.setChecked(true);
        lastToggled = position;
    } else {
        viewHolder.toggletable.setChecked(false);
    }

    viewHolder.toggletable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                table.setTableSelected(true);
// notify ChildAdapter and group.setGroupSelected(false)
                if (lastToggled >= 0) {
                    tablelist.get(lastToggled).setTableSelected(false);
// notify ChildAdapter and group.setGroupSelected(false)
                    notifyItemChanged(lastToggled);
                }
                lastToggled = position;
            } else {
                table.setTableSelected(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow. `The problem is this helper class cant get the Buttons which are off-screen.` I think you are missing the fundamentals of the RecyclerView, can you please post your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method? The RecyclerView touches only widgets that are currently visible to the user. That's why it has better performance and you probably have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the fundamentals of the RecyclerView. That's why I said "the closest" I came up with. It doesn't really work how it should. I need a solution that manages the "off-screen" buttons as well.

Comment: Clearly you are missing something. RecyclerView is not aware of the "off-screen" items, and will never been, except if you "wrap_content" on its height which you shouldn't as it will be awfully against its own design. Your problem possibly lies within your adapters, can you share some snippets please?

Comment: I know that RecyclerView is not aware of the "off-screen" items. That's the issue I can not seem to manage. My adapters code is very very big but doesn't contain any selection logic since so far it was managed by the helper-class. Its just binding views. That's why I haven't posted any Adapter code.

Comment: You don't need a  helper class, this kind of logic could be in your adapter. The adapter has their own collection of elements which could notify the adapter about changes to children, etc. [notifyDatasetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifydatasetchanged). Once that's called the binding will happen again. Your elements should rather have some kind of UI state saying whether or not to mark them selected or not when the onBindViewHolder is called either due to a notify or a widget coming on the screen.

Comment: You are absolutely right thats why I'm aking here! I have seen single selection in one Adapter but never with a nested RecyclerView.

Comment: Edited with more code

Comment: @NilsRamon Any luck? please share your solution if you found any.

Comment: Nothing so far, im collecting some reputation so i can bounty it.

Comment: @iUser updated!

Comment: I made it work too. Thanks for the response anyways :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Managed to come up with a solution myself, although 100% sure, not the best approach.

First of all, implement Greenrobots EventBus:

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

Now in the Activity where you hold both RecyclerViews register the Event listener:

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
```

and subscribe 2 methods. One for Parent Events and one for Children Events. This methods will trigger every time an item is selected!

```
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onParentEventClicked(ParentAdapter.ParentEvent event) {
// to access the inner adapter here you must set it to public in the ParentAdapter(public ChildAdapter adapter;)
        adapter.adapter.deSelectChild();
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onChildEventClicked(ChildAdapter.ChildEvent event) {
// normal ParentAdapter reference(ParentAdapter adapter;)
        adapter.deSelectParent();
    }
```

Inside your ParentAdapter create a method to deselect all parent items and a static class to fire the event:

```
public void deSelectParent()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
        {
            data.get(i).setSelected(false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

public static class ParentEvent {
        View view;
        int position;
    }
```

Inside your ChildAdapter create a method to deselect all child items and a static class to fire the event:

```
public void deSelectChild()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
        {
            datachild.get(i).setSelected(false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

public static class ChildEvent {
        View view;
        int position;
    }
```

now in both Parent and Child onBindViewHolders, you need similar logic for your models:

```
if (item.isSelected()) {
                holder.yourbutton.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                holder.yourbutton.setChecked(false);
            }

holder.yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ParentEvent event = new ParentEvent();
                    event.view = holder.yourbutton;
                    event.position = position;
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
                    if (holder.yourbutton.isChecked()) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                            data.get(i).setSelected(false);
                        }
                        data.get(position).setSelected(true);
                    } else {
                        data.get(position).setSelected(false);
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

And thats pretty much it, every click on a ParentItem will trigger the deselect method for ChildAdapter and vice-versa.
Due to the high usage of notifyDataSetChanged() I recommend using this line to get rid of the blinking:

```
 recycler_view_parent.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Any problems let me know!